# GeoDjango--Python:Can't Display Map

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm getting troubled (more troubled i guess) in displaying my map (from postgresql database) under Geodjango environment. . i had already successfully imported my shapefile into Posgresql database. Yet, I cannot view my maps whenever I tried to. . i also followed the steps in installing all the libraries needed, django, python and postgresql. .

I am new to Geodjango that's why I cannot trace errors. . and actually i dont nknow how. . maybe i could get help from you guys. .

I always get these errors. .
it talks about templates. .
i have also my template folder on my project folder. . yet its empty and dont know what it is for. .

can you please help me out on this. ?

more thanks to you and i really appreciate you guys for helping out. .

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/APPLICATION/worldborder/245/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.0 
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'APPLICATION')
Installed Middleware:
 ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\gis\admin\osm.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\gis\admin\osm.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\gis\admin\osm.html (File does not exist)



Template error:
In template C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 19
  gis/admin/osm.html
  9 :             {% for field in line %}


  10 :                 <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="field-box{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>


  11 :                     {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not   field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}


  12 :                     {% if field.is_checkbox %}


  13 :                         {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}


  14 :                     {% else %}


  15 :                         {{ field.label_tag }}


  16 :                         {% if field.is_readonly %}


  17 :                             <p>{{ field.contents|linebreaksbr }}</p>


  18 :                         {% else %}


  19 :                              {{ field.field }} 


 20 :                         {% endif %}


 21 :                     {% endif %}


 22 :                     {% if field.field.help_text %}


 23 :                         <p class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>


 24 :                     {% endif %}


 25 :                 </div>


 26 :             {% endfor %}


 27 :         </div>


 28 :     {% endfor %}


 29 : </fieldset>


 Traceback:
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
 139.                 response = response.render()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
 105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
 82.         content = template.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
 140.             return self._render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
 134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
 840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
 78.             return node.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
   123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
   134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
   840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
   78.             return node.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
   123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
   134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
   840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
   78.             return node.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
   62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
   840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
   78.             return node.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
   62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
   840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
   78.             return node.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
   196.                         nodelist.append(node.render(context))
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
   155.         return self.render_template(self.template, context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render_template
   137.         output = template.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
   140.             return self._render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
   134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
   840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
   78.             return node.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
   196.                         nodelist.append(node.render(context))
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
   196.                         nodelist.append(node.render(context))
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
   305.                 return nodelist.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
   840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
   78.             return node.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
   305.                 return nodelist.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
   840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
   78.             return node.render(context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render
   91.             output = force_text(output)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py" in force_text
   100.                 s = s.__unicode__()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in __str__
   425.         return self.as_widget()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in as_widget
   475.         return widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\widgets.py" in render
   81.                                        context_instance=geo_context)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
   162.         t = get_template(template_name)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
   138.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in find_template
   131.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

 Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/APPLICATION/worldborder/245/
 Exception Value: gis/admin/osm.html
```

Comment: You might want to learn a bit about [Django](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html) first and how it is build.

Answer (score 4):

The first map you can create very easily is in your **Admin section**

admin.py

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from .models import MyLayer

admin.site.register(MyLayer, admin.GeoModelAdmin)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.contrib.gis import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Check that admin app is enable in settings.py.

Then go to your navigator localhost/myapp/admin.
You should see a map in your item's description.

---

**Other way**: Get your geom data in python, make a GeoJSON out of it and send it to an OpenLayer map:

requires vectorformats and simplejson packages

views.py

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from vectorformats.Formats import Django, GeoJSON

from mysite.models import MyLayer


def geojson(request):
    ly = MyLayer.objects.filter(name='xxx')
    djf = Django.Django(geodjango='mpoly', properties=['name'])
    geoj = GeoJSON.GeoJSON()
    my_geojson = geoj.encode(djf.decode(ly))
    return render(request, "mysite_temp/map.html", {'my_geojson': my_geojson})
```

In templates, create mysite_temp folder and map.html file.
If you write only `{ {my_geojson} }` in map.html you will see the content of the GeoJSON

create OpenLayer map in map.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script> 
    <style>
        html,body {
            height: 99%;
            width: 99%;
        }
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }   
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;

            function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
                var base_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
               "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'} );
            map.addLayer(base_layer);

        var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("layername");
        map.addLayer(layer);

        var format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
        var feat = format.read({{my_geojson|safe}});  
        layer.addFeatures(feat);

        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(l_val,L_val),zoom_val);
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
       }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "init()">
    <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Cheers!

Comment: @hey jcs . . tnx a lot for answering my post. . it was really helpful. . i got my map displayed on web. .

Comment: I also got problems pertaining to srid. . transforming it in OpenLayers doesn't solve anything. . I am using  base_layer =  new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap"); as my base layer. . and when i set my map center, it doesn't point to where i desired it to be. . and also geojson file doesn't overlay on the location it should be. . i suppose that i got problem on the projection. . how will i fix this?? can you help me?? BTW, i really appreciate you answering my post. . tnx a lot. .

Comment: Hi, it definitly has something to do with your projection. OSM is in EPSG:3857 Spherical Mercator.

Comment: Hi, it definitly has something to do with your projection. OSM is in EPSG:3857 Spherical Mercator. So be sure you source is too. You might want to add `ly.transform(3857)` between your object request and making the GeoJSON.

Comment: hi @jcs. . i really appreciate you for helping. . it worked. .. Thanks a lot. . i think it's a best start for me in using django . .more thanks to you . .

Comment: could I display multiple vector layers on a single map?? I was trying to declare two models of spatial data in my models.py. . i was also thinking that it might be possible by having them in a single models.py but the approach has given me error. . how will i display it?? and ohh, i'm sorry for asking too many questions, i just want to learn form you. . ^_^

Comment: of course you can! Just make an other _mygeojson_ using an other class from your models.py. Pass it to the return. Then in JS add an other layer. Everything should be the same.

Comment: i tried your process and it worked ! ^_^ . .by the way, do you have any references, I mean sites/tutorials,  which can be  of help to me?? i am trying to append data to the database. . it's adding polygon to the database through django. . :)

Comment: look into django admin site. If your geodjango settings are well it should be easy. Don't have much to point you to. I do it all by myself and stuff i find here and there (lots of stackoverflow). I would be glad if you could accept my answer since everything i helped you with worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: i really appreciate you helping me. . thank you so much. . i'll try on the admin. . ^.^

Comment: hi again @jcs. i was trying to query feature from my database through a user input. . i try displaying the feature and everything is the same using vectorformats. .i have it posted here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368355/vectorformats-and-openlayers i hope you'll try seeing this. . thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How to add StyleMap on each multipolygon with @jcs example

example

```
 // Style fuer Polygon
var polygon_style = {

        fillColor : '${color}',
        strokeColor : '${color}',
        strokeOpacity : "0.9",
        fillOpacity : "0.2"
};

geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
    projection : projLonLat,
    strategies : [ new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed() ],
    protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url : url_geoJSON_Polygon,
        format : new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    styleMap :new OpenLayers.StyleMap(polygon_style)
});

map.addLayer(geojson_layer);
```

With this geoJSON

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {"color": "#2EFE2E"},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      13.41379165649414,
      52.54431222846979
    ]
  }
}
```